# zabbix agent tls support

Tags: zabbix, zabbix-agent

I'm installing zabbix agent on my machines and i've noticed that sometimes the agent doesn't have the `TLS` lines

```
### Option: TLSKeyFile
#   Full pathname of a file containing the agent private key.
#
# Mandatory: no
# Default:
# TLSKeyFile=

### Option: TLSPSKIdentity
#   Unique, case sensitive string used to identify the pre-shared key.
#
# Mandatory: no
# Default:
# TLSPSKIdentity=

### Option: TLSPSKFile
#   Full pathname of a file containing the pre-shared key.
#
# Mandatory: no
# Default:
# TLSPSKFile=
```

So when I add those parameters, the agent won't start.

Can someone tell me what am I missing  ?

Comment: Which operating system? Which version of the agent? Where/how did you obtain it? What values do you add in the configuration file? How do you start the agent and how does that fail?

Comment: I'd bet it's using openssl libs, not always available

Comment: actually it's because of the zabbix-agent version. it was 2.8 and when I upgraded it to 3.0 it was fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> So when I add those parameters, the agent won't start.
>
> Can someone tell me what am I missing ?

Entries from your log files that would give you some clues as to what is happening.

I would go looking for the zabbix agent log file and see what relevant error messages it has then work from there.

The zabbix agent log file is frequently found in `/var/log/zabbix` and could be named `zabbix_agentd.log` but YMMV depending on distro and or OS.

You may also get some useful information out of other system logs or even journalctl.

Comment: Actually i just had to upgrade my zabbix-agent version, I select ur answer as correct anyway  thanks

Answer (score 0):

You need to reinstall the zabbix-agent service.

```
net stop "Zabbix Agent"
<fullpath>\zabbix_agentd.exe -d
<fullpath>\zabbix_agentd.exe -i -c <path to proper config file> 
net start "Zabbix Agent"
```

Beside I have noticed that on some Windows Servers like 2003 32 bit when I install the agent I have a problem with start service cause of using file with tls config.

Comment: Please remember to use capital I and right text formatting options. Welcome to SF.